# Get the sum of the value selected from different query of MySQL - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the average of the sum I get with this queries

**This is my query**

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(title) as count_title, SUM(average) as total_average FROM table_1 WHERE name='name1' GROUP BY title");
$query2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(title) as count_title, SUM(average) as total_average FROM table_1 WHERE name='name2' GROUP BY title");
```

**My table_1**

```
id     average     title     name 

 1         5       title_aa  name1
 2         4       title_aa  name1
 3         4       title_ab  name1
 4         3       title_ac  name1
 5         2       title_aa  name2
 6         1       title_ab  name2
 7         2       title_ab  name2
```

**PHP**

```
while($values = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
    $count_title = $values['count_title'];
    $total_average = $values['total_average'];
    $total = $total_average / $count_title;
    $title = $values[2];

    echo "Title:" . $title . "<br>";
    echo "Average:" . $total . "<br>";
}

while($values2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){
    $count_title2 = $values2['count_title'];
    $total_average2 = $values2['total_average'];
    $total2 = $total_average2 / $count_title2;
    $title2 = $values2[2];

    echo "Title:" . $title2 . "<br>";
    echo "Average:" . $total2 . "<br>";
}
```

**OUTPUT OF THE $query1**

Title: title_aa

Average: 4.5

Title: title_ab

Average: 4.0

Title: title_ac

Average: 3.0

**OUTPUT OF THE $query2**

Title: title_aa

Average: 2.0

Title: title_ab

Average: 1.5

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

Title: title_aa

Average: 3.25 // total of (4.5 + 2.0) / 2

Title: title_ab

Average: 2.75 // total of (4.0 + 1.5) / 2

Title: title_ac

Average: 3.0

Comment: did you try the avg() function of mysql??

Comment: yes i tried that one and get the average of different titles like what i posted, but what i want is the average of two average i get from two different queries

Comment: What about this? `SELECT title,AVG(average) AS average FROM table_1 GROUP BY title;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can replace your two queries with the following using AVG() function

mysql code:

```
 SELECT title, AVG(average) average FROM table_1 WHERE name='name1' GROUP BY title
 SELECT title, AVG(average) average FROM table_1 WHERE name='name2' GROUP BY title
```

2. so, you can have the average of averages using one request:

mysql code:

```
SELECT t1.title, (AVG(t1.average)+AVG(t2.average))/2
   FROM table_1 t1 JOIN table_1 t2 ON t1.title=t2.title
   WHERE t1.name='name1' AND t2.name='name2'
   GROUP BY t1.title;
```

3. EDIT, after the first comment

The previous request does not include elements that are not belonging to both name1 and name2. You can so, do the following:

```
 SELECT title,
  (IFNULL(AVG(IF(t1.name='name1', average, NULL)), 0) 
   + IFNULL(AVG(IF(t1.name='name2', average, NULL)), 0))
   /COUNT(DISTINCT name)
 FROM table_1 t1
 GROUP by title;
```

Comment: This one will return only `title_aa` and `title_ab`

Comment: hi mate, may i know what function is the one you used in putting t1. variable in query.

Comment: Nothing, just a shorthand which is of no use when you have only one table. Might be some copy/paste residue...

Answer (score 1):

save both values of first and second result in two different array..
like for first query

```
$data=array();
while($values = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
    $count_title = $values['count_title'];
    $total_average = $values['total_average'];
    $total = $total_average / $count_title;
    $title = $values[2];
    $data[]=$total;
    echo "Title:" . $title . "<br>";
    echo "Average:" . $total . "<br>";
}
```

and for second query

```
$data2=array();
while($values2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){
    $count_title2 = $values2['count_title'];
    $total_average2 = $values2['total_average'];
    $total2 = $total_average2 / $count_title2;
    $title2 = $values2[2];
    $data2[]=$total2;
    echo "Title:" . $title2 . "<br>";
    echo "Average:" . $total2 . "<br>";
}
```

now using for loop

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($data);$i++)
{
 $avg=($data[$i]+$data2[$i])/2;
 echo $avg;
}
```

Comment: @rick jan cawaling try this.